# Keep CMake from from installing the import library when installing a shared library

Tags: cmake

The title pretty much already sums up my problem:
When creating a library with `add_library(SHARED)`, cmake creates two files, the actual library (.so/.dll) and the import library (.a/.lib)

That, by itself, is not a problem.

But when I call `install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION ${DeploymentFolder})`, it also installs both files, the shared library and its import.

I only want the shared library to be installed, because they're only being used as runtime libraries. They're not supposed to be linked to anything but the executable also in the deployment folder.

Any ideas aside from using `FILES` to specify the name explicitly?

FWIW, the environment is a Qt installation on Windows.

Comment: Less than optimal, but `install(FILES $<TARGET_FILE:${projectName}> DESTINATION ${DeploymentFolder})` does the job.

Comment: In the title you write "Keep Cmake from generating .. import library", but without the import library you cannot link your executable with the shared library. Could "generating" part will be edited out from the title?

Comment: Can do, @Tsyvarev. I also amended the title to better address the actual gripe. (The import library being installed automatically).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMake supports several **kinds of artifacts** which can be installed. By default, for a SHARED library on Windows both RUNTIME (`.dll`) and ARCHIVE (`.lib`) are selected ([documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#targets)). But you may explicitly specify which artifacts you need:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  RUNTIME # Installs only '.dll' part of the library
  DESTINATION ${DeploymentFolder})
```

If you want to support both Windows and Linux, you may specify RUNTIME and LIBRARY kinds: the latter one is for installing `.so`:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
  RUNTIME # Installs only '.dll' part of the shared library on Windows
          # Does nothing for libraries on Linux
    DESTINATION ${DeploymentFolder}
  LIBRARY # Installs shared library on Linux
          # Does nothing for shared libraries on Windows
    DESTINATION ${DeploymentFolder})
```

Comment: How weird, I thought I had tried that...but apparently not.
Works, thank you.